# Installed SSL certificate is in the binding correctly for IIS website

Tags: ssl, iis, ssl-certificate

We have a number of internal apps which have website access - this is set up on Windows Server 2016 through IIS.

We create the SSL certificate for these apps through "Certify the Web". These are updated automatically. These SSL certificates are binded to the websites through IIS and seem to update automatically as required.

However when we navigate to these websites they state that the SSL certificates are invalid, with the old dated certificate which expired a while ago.

Anything you guys suggest for this?

Comment: https://docs.jexusmanager.com/tutorials/ssl-diagnostics.html You might run a report to see whether something is wrong on the server. If everything is fine on IIS, you have the network devices in between (reverse proxy and so on) to review.

Comment: Check the binding of these sites, make sure they are correct. Then try to reboot the server and access sites again.